# Dynamic check boxes in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in a point where i need to show check boxes dynamically depending on selected value of dropdownlist. I have code for this in which i can use for loop till the number i want, but is there any way to reduce long lengthy code.
Below is my code.

```
     if(drop_val == 'test')
        {
            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "name";
            checkbox.value = "value";
            checkbox.id = "chk_id";

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = "chk_id";
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test'));


            document.getElementById('check').appendChild(checkbox);
            document.getElementById('check').appendChild(label);


        }.
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330202/how-to-create-list-of-checkboxes-dynamically-with-javascript

Comment: use jquery such as $('<input type="checkbox" name="name" id="check_id">')

Answer (score 0):

There are more compact ways to do all that with jQuery or concatenating HTML, but however you choose to implement it, if you're doing it more than once, put it in a function with a sensible name. I'm guessing (let me know if I guessed wrong!) that you want more compact code because you're copying and pasting it into a bunch of `if` blocks. That's a very bad idea. It's horrible to read and rapidly becomes unmaintainable.

A second-rate option, still better than copying and pasting the whole wad, is to declare four variables -- the parameters to the function below -- before your if/else chain, and do nothing in those if blocks but assign different ids or whatever to the variables. Then create the checkbox *once* at the end of the whole thing, using the variables you set up. Either way, you write the creation code once and feed it *parameters* which alter its behavior. This is called "parameterization", for reasons which must now be all too obvious.

And it lets you turn any long and messy piece of code into a self-documenting one-word function call, without having to rely on anything clever about the environment. Of course you should learn all you can about the environment: Very often, somebody else already wrote exactly the function you need, but you can't count on that.

```
if (drop_val == 'test')
{
    createCheckbox('check', 'blah', 'Blah blah blah', false);
}
else if ( drop_val == 'Mae West' )
{
    createCheckbox('check', 'maewest', 'Va va va voom', false);
}

//  Snip...

function createCheckbox(parentID, chkID, labelText, isChecked)
{
    var cb = document.createElement('input');

    cb.type = "checkbox";
    cb.name = chkID;
    cb.value = "yes";
    cb.id = chkID;
    cb.checked = isChecked;

    var lbl = document.createElement('label')
    lbl.htmlFor = chkID;
    lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(labelText));

    document.getElementById(parentID).appendChild(cb);
    document.getElementById(parentID).appendChild(lbl);

    //  If nobody wants this, they can just ignore it. 
    return { checkbox: cb, label: lbl };
}
```