# javascript: create dynamic checkbox from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu which get the values dynamically from an array with a `foreach` loop. I know that the javascript `"getElementById"` need a unique key. The problem is that my unique key is a combination of `"service_select"` and `"$value2"`. So that every service can be more than one.

The only unique key I have from the dropdown elements is the variable `$value`.

```
<?php
echo'<select id="service_name" name="service_select">';
foreach($array_name_new as $key=>$value)
{
   echo'<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';

echo'<p>Parameter:  <input name=\"$value2\" value=\"$value2\'/></p>';    
?>
```

For each selected value in the dropbox I want a "checkbox" with the dropbox selection as name and value. I need although a seperate textfield with `"$value2"` as value.

I have already found this thread  ([How to create list of checkboxes dynamically with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330202/how-to-create-list-of-checkboxes-dynamically-with-javascript)), but I'm a newbe to javascript and don't understand the code completely.

- What does the `if` clause in function `"function populate()"`? Is
  this for generating the checkboxes?
- Where has the codepart in the answer be added into the original code?

According to the mentioned thread I tried to modify my code like this:

```
<?PHP
.
.
.   
echo'<select id="service" name="service_select" onchange="add_service(this.id,$_POST['service_select'],$value2)">';
  foreach($array_command_name_new as $key=>$value)
  {
  echo'<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
  }
echo'</select>';

$key2 = array_search($value,$command_in_hostfile[0]);
$value2 = $command_in_hostfile[1][$key2];

$id2 = compact("$_POST['service_select']", "value2");

<script type="text/javascript">         
function add_service($id2, $_POST['service_select'], $value2)
{
foreach($array_command_name_new as $key=>$value)
  {         
  var elementid = docuemnt.getElementById($id2);
  var checkbox = document.createElement('id');
  checkbox.type = "checked";
  checkbox.name = "$_POST['service_select']";
  checkbox.value = "$_POST['service_select']";
  checkbox.id = "$id";
  var label = document.createElement('$_POST['service_select']')
  label.htmlFor = "id";
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('$_POST['service_select']');
  container.appendChild(checkbox);
  container.appendChild(label);
  }

echo'<p>Parameter:  <input id="parameter" name=\"$value2\" value=\"$value2\' onclick="addService('value_parameter')" /> </p>';
var s1 = document.getElementById($id2);
}
</script>
.
.
.
?>
```

I would be pleased if anyone can help me.

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand from code of the linked thread? You can use the DOM-Inspector for Firefox to understand what your linked thread talked about. For that create a very simple html page. The DOM-Inspector can show the elements hirachy of your created site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the solution will be a bit more complex... you need to add inputs to your form for every value the user selects...

Something like this:

```
[Option a]     Parameter: [__________]    [X]
[Option b]     Parameter: [__________]    [X]

[Please select... ][v]
```

Every time a user selects a new option you must add a new line to allow the parameter to be entered.

You will then  need a [X] button in each line so the user can remove unwanted entries.

This is Javascript intensive :)

Comment: My primary idea was, that the user select the option in the dropdown and add the parameter as text.  Via Javascript I want only write the checkbox with the value from the menu and the textfiled with the parameter.