# How to make checkbox events from dynamically created checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I have three parameters namely model, destination and criteria. Whenever the user chooses a model from the dropdown list, where the destination and criteria is dependent, dynamic checkboxes for the destination is shown. And when a user tick a destination, its specific criteria will show. This is a follow up question: [How to display multiple list of checkboxes dynamically on dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306336/how-to-display-multiple-list-of-checkboxes-dynamically-on-dropdown-list?noredirect=1#comment91561947_52306336)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(model, destination) {
        var mod = document.getElementById(model);
        var des = document.getElementById(destination);
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (mod.value == "model-a") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-b") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-B.1", "Model-B.2", "Model-B.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-c") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-C.1", "Model-C.2", "Model-C.3"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;
            des.appendChild(checkbox);
    
            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            des.appendChild(label);
            des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

SELECT MODEL:
<select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 'destination')">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="model-a">MODEL-A</option>
   <option value="model-b">MODEL-B</option>
   <option value="model-c">MODEL-C</option>
</select>
<hr />
SELECT DESTINATION:
<div id="destination"></div>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me with adding such events. Iam new and still learning javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try my solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function populate(model, destination) {
        var mod = document.getElementById(model);
        var des = document.getElementById(destination);
        des.innerHTML = "";
        if (mod.value == "model-a") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-A.1", "Model-A.2", "Model-A.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-b") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-B.1", "Model-B.2", "Model-B.3"];
        } else if (mod.value == "model-c") {
            var optionArray = ["Model-C.1", "Model-C.2", "Model-C.3"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
        if (optionArray.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            var pair = optionArray[option];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = pair;
            checkbox.value = pair;

            //I added the below statement
            checkbox.onclick=updateCriteria;
            //I added the above statment                    

            des.appendChild(checkbox);

            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = pair;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(pair));

            des.appendChild(label);
            des.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));    
        }
    }
}
function updateCriteria()
{
    switch(this.value)
    {
        case "Model-A.1":alert(this.value+" is a dog.");
                         break;
        case "Model-A.2":alert(this.value+" is a cat.");
                         break;  
    }
    this.checked=false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

SELECT MODEL:
<select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 'destination');">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="model-a">MODEL-A</option>
   <option value="model-b">MODEL-B</option>
   <option value="model-c">MODEL-C</option>
</select>
<hr />
SELECT DESTINATION:
<div id="destination"></div>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the process is somehow like that but I need to display specific data like when checkbox1 is clicked, "dog" will be displayed. When checkbox2 is clicked, "cat" will be displayed. @the KNVB

Comment: it only mirrors the selected checkbox name. What I mean is that if I check, for example the Model-A.1, it will show that Model-A.1 is a dog. If I check Model-A.2, it will show that Model-A.2 is a cat. @the KNVB

Comment: you can use if - then - else  or switch - case structure to do so.

Comment: is it possible? since the criteria will be dependent on the model and destination @the KNVB

Comment: Why not? Any difficulties you facing?

Comment: I can't put a value that is dependent on the checkbox and dropdown list. Like if I chose option Model-A, tick Model-A.1 then the criteria should be a dog. Or if I chose option Model-A, tick Model-A.2 the criteria should be bird and etc.... @the KNVB

Comment: How can I display all the values checked in a table? and at the same time, remove the values that becomes unchecked @The KNVB

Comment: For "remove the values that becomes unchecked", you can check the updated code. For adding value to a table you may refer my sample code to implement it by your self. Sample code URL:https://jsfiddle.net/bs9c5ka6/4/

Comment: Slight changes has to be made and its driving me nuts! How can I display criteria values together with its textboxes with respect to the destination and model? Criteria will no longer depend on the checked box, but it will already show all the criteria values and the checked destination will only get the values of the criteria and its textbox @The KNVB

Comment: I suggest you search javascript dom tutorial in google, and then learn and try by yourself. Good luck.

Comment: You may see the following video to learn javascript dom by yourself:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIORjGvT0kk

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to attach event to the dynamically created element

```
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.name = pair;
                checkbox.value = pair;
                checkbox.id = "desCheckBox";
                des.appendChild(checkbox);

               //eventname is name of the event
               // here id is "desCheckBox"
                document.addEventListener('eventname', function (e) {
                    if (e.target && e.target.id == 'id') {
                        // do something
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a class className to the checkbox you're creating and write an event applying to that class name. checkbox.className = "class_Name"

You can write this code at the level of your populate method.

```
$(".class_Name").unbind();
$(".class_Name").on("change", function () {
   //this will give you access to the checkbox item being changed
});
```