# Jquery enter event on dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to get an enter event on dynamically created div, What I'm trying to do is :

```
$('.emojionearea-editor').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
        alert('Enter pressed');
    }
});
```

but it's not working the way it has to, this  div `.emojionearea-editor` is created on the run time and I'm not able to get it's <kbd>enter</kbd> event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: you can refer code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309011/how-to-make-checkbox-events-from-dynamically-created-checkbox-javascript/52309345#52309345

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
(function(){
  $(document).on('keypress', '.emojionearea-editor', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
        alert('Enter pressed');
    }
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="emojionearea-editor">
```