# How do I retrieve the value from a checkbox that was created from a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was following the sample code provided by another post (source: [How to display multiple list of checkboxes dynamically on dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306336/how-to-display-multiple-list-of-checkboxes-dynamically-on-dropdown-list)), as it has the function that was exactly what I was trying to do for my webpage. However, I am having trouble retrieving the value of the checkbox that the user has selected, as the checkbox was dynamically created from the javascript. I tried debugging by inserting an alert function, and I was return with a "[Object NodeList]".

How can I retrieve the individual value(s) base on the checkbox that the user has selected?
For example, if user has selected "apple", I want to retrieve the value "apple". But if the user has selected "apple" and "Orange", I want to retrieve the value "apple" and "orange".

**UPDATE**

Thank you everyone for your comments and sample codes. I have edited the code below to retrieve the user-selected checkbox.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="product_form">
  <div class="row" id="row1">
      <div class="col-8">
          <label><strong>FoodCategory:</strong></label>
          <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 'food')">
              <option value="select">--Select Category--</option>
              <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
              <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
          <label><strong>Outcome:</strong></label>
          <div id="food"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
<button onclick="getResult()">Get Result</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var mappingData = {
    "fruit": {
      "destination": ["Apple", "Orage"]
    },
    "vegetable": {
      "destination": ["Cabbage", "Carrot"]
    }
  };
  
  function populate(model, food) {
    var mod = document.getElementById('model');
    var scenario = document.getElementById('food');
    scenario.innerHTML = "";
    mappingData[mod.value].destination.forEach(function(item) {
      createCheckBox(item, scenario)
    });
  }
  
  function createCheckBox(value, parent) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "food";
    checkbox.value = value;
  
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.htmlFor = value;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
  
    parent.appendChild(checkbox)
    parent.appendChild(label)
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"))
  }

function getResult() {
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="food"]:checked');
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value)
    });
    alert(values);
}
```

Comment: there is no element with document.getElementById('food');

Comment: My apology, I had changed some of the names before posting the code here. Please find the updated code. Thanks

Comment: Furthermore if you want multiple selection and correlation between them, your checkbox elements must have the same name attribute.   In this way will be returned an array of checkbox correlated and you can check with the property `checked` which is checked

Comment: `<option value="fruit">` not `<option value="Fruit">` otherwise that select won't work.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I understood what you mean. Thanks for the comment, I was able to retrieve the value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write this code when all javascript code done...

```
<script> 
if (document.getElementById('youid').checked) {
        alert(document.getElementById('youid').value);
    }</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an attribute to select those checkboxes, this code would work:

```js
function do_submit(form) {

  var result = [];
  var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll(".my-checkbox").forEach(function(elem) {
    if (elem.checked) {
      result.push(elem.value);
    }
  });
  form.querySelector("[name=chekboxes]").value = result.join(",");


  // to cancel:
  return false

  // to submit:
  // form.submit();


}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return do_submit(this); ">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="apple"> apple </label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="banana"> banana </label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="my-checkbox" value="cabbage"> cabbage </label><br>

  <!-- should be hidden: -->
  <input type="text" name="chekboxes" value="">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```